# Best practises React hooks HTTP loading

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I recently started another project with react, as I had a little time to fiddle around, I used functional components with hooks. I had no problem whatsoever, there's just one thing I'm not sure I use correctly, here is an example :

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);

  var getDataFromHTTP = async () { ... }

  var loadData = async () => {
    if (!dataLoaded) {
      setDataLoaded(true);
      setData(await getDataFromHTTP());
    }
  }

  loadData();

  return( ... );
}
```

If I like how everything is done, I suppose it's dirty to use loadData(); like in the preceding example, and I tried to useEffect with something like this :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  loadData();
}, []);
```

but then I got a warning like "loadData should be a dependency of useEffect". If I omit the the second argument to useEffect, it looks like it's the same as putting it directly in MyComponent. So basically, my question, in this example what is the best practise to load data once when the component is mounted ? and of course, when props/state change, what is the best practise to reload it if needed ?

EDIT:
The warning I have with useEffect is :

```
[Warning] ./src/list/main.js (1.chunk.js, line 25568)
Line 53:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loadData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Comment: Looking at https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data , your code with `useEffect()` looks fine. The only strange thing is that in `loadData()` you're not `await`ing the call to `getDataFromHTTP` which is `async`, maybe `setData(<promise>)` causes the issue? Try to `let result = await getDataFromHTTP(); setData(result);` and let us know how it goes :) also, the mentioned article might help. Cheers

Comment: Oops, that's a code I wrote as a smaller example, I forgot await. Anyway, my code works, I'm just asking about how I should do it the "best way"

Comment: I was going for the second option as the "best way" and trying to fix the error. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way useEffect works is whenever something in the dependencies array change React will run that effect

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadData();
}, [loadData]); // <-- dependencies array
```

But as you have declared `loadData` as a normal function it will get re-assigned to a new function on every render and it will trigger the effect.
Best way would be to wrap your `loadData` function in an useCallback hook

```
const loadData = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!dataLoaded) {
      setDataLoaded(true);
      setData(await getDataFromHTTP());
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: skyboyer, yes, of course, and there will be parameters. I just don't get why a const function would have to be declared as a dependency. I still think there is too much code for a small feat, and I don't understand why. I'll continue trying to get it ^^'

Comment: Not sure what you meant by this 'why a const function would have to be declared as a dependency' can you explain more, maybe I can help.

Comment: I got it, I reread your explanation, it was clear enough, make a hook to a function to avoid being confronted to a 'new' function on every render.